# Как получить title страницы в шаблоне nuxt?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Как получить title страницы в шаблоне nuxt если title задан в отдельном файле который является частью общего шаблона?

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в `nuxtjs` возможно добавить `title` двумя способами:

1. в `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - Nuxt.js',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },

      // hid is used as unique identifier. Do not use `vmid` for it as it will not work
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Meta description' }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. используя метод страницы `head()`

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        // hid is used as unique identifier. Do not use `vmid` for it as it will not work
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My custom description' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Скорее всего, как и `asyncData`, `head` не сработает в компоненте, этот метод работает только в страницах (*.vue файлах лежащих в папке /pages).

Получить же в `title` в самом шаблоне, можно например так:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.title = document.title
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно Вас понял и ещё актуально:

```
this.$meta().resume().metaInfo.title
```

Подробнее: [nuxt.js - meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#meta-resume)